# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' after pip install

Tags: python, pycharm

I know similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I am getting the following error message after trying to import requests:

```
C:\Users\Jm\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Jm/PycharmProjects/Test/Test_001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jm/PycharmProjects/Test/Test_001", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I only have one version of python installed and `python -m pip` install requests is saying all the requirements are already satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code:

```
C:\Users\Jm\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install requests
```

This forces the installation directory to your python install.

This gives a much different effect than simply `python -m pip install requests`

Comment: Accepted as answer. Small question though, how can I make sure every new python project can use this module without having to reinstall it every time?

Comment: Good question: `C:\Users\Jm\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe` is not your only installation of python. If you want this work reliably, you will need to path the \path\to\python for each install you use and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Scott mentioned before use the command mentioned above or below

***$: path-to-your-python-command -m pip install name-of-module***

If you are using linux/mac then you can find path-to-your-python command using:

***$: which python3***

/usr/bin/python3

Lets say your python is installed here **/usr/bin/python3** and the module you are installing is **requests**. Then you can use:

***$: /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install requests***