# ModuleNotFoundError after pip install . (custom module)

Tags: python, pip

I am starting a custom package called nate-givens-toolkit.

I want to use a module from that package in a Jupyter notebook in a different folder.

Here is my structure

```
- nate-givens-toolkit/
  - setup.py
  - nate_givens_toolkit/
    - cloud_io.py
    - __init__.py
- project/
  - project_nb.ipynb
```

I am going into nate_givens_toolkit (in the console) and running: `pip3 install .`

The output I get looks like everything is just fine.

```
Processing /home/ec2-user/nate-givens-toolkit
Building wheels for collected packages: nate-givens-tooklit
  Building wheel for nate-givens-tooklit (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for nate-givens-tooklit: filename=nate_givens_tooklit-0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=2009 sha256=7de8c9d2930d531603c973c7d8079b66f3d4326fb274e63087128fb7d25d9e1b
  Stored in directory: /home/ec2-user/.cache/pip/wheels/17/96/2f/0073c92cfdadbb032d855f24df4725bf190d39cd1c5bb1d233
Successfully built nate-givens-tooklit
Installing collected packages: nate-givens-tooklit
  Attempting uninstall: nate-givens-tooklit
    Found existing installation: nate-givens-tooklit 0.1
    Uninstalling nate-givens-tooklit-0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled nate-givens-tooklit-0.1
Successfully installed nate-givens-tooklit-0.1
```

But if I go into project_nb.ipynb and write:

`from nate_givens_toolkit import cloud_io as cloud`

I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nate_givens_toolkit'

The same thing happens if I run python from the console. As long as I'm in the nate-givens-toolkit directory I can import and run it fine. But if I navigate up a level and try the import I get ModuleNotFoundError.

I don't understand why pip install seems to work, but I still get this ModuleNotFoundError. I thought the whole point of the pip install would be that I could then import from files in other directory without having to worry about relative paths and such. (I've done this exact same thing in a totally different context for work and it was fine.)

I've tried the solutions for similar issues like these:

- [after pip successful installed: ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528638/after-pip-successful-installed-modulenotfounderror)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084263/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-after-pip-install)

So far, haven't found anything that works.

Everything I'm doing is inside the same conda venv.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here: [Import py file in another directory in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264194/import-py-file-in-another-directory-in-jupyter-notebook). (Note: it wasn't the accepted answer on that post, it was the second answer *after* the accepted answer.)

The trick is that I needed to do use the -e flag when using pip install.

So instead of

`pip install .`

I had to run

`pip install -e .`

Once I ran that, it worked in Python from the console and also in Jupyter.